# Putting a javascript code into a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm editing a web program in MySQL; unfortunately, I got stuck with the following:

A smarty markup, used to display a form, has the following value:

```
{php}
$format = $this->get_template_vars("phone_number_format");
$values = explode("|", $this->get_template_vars("VALUE"));
$name   = $this->get_template_vars("NAME");

$pieces = preg_split("/(x+)/", $format, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$counter = 1;
foreach ($pieces as $piece)
{
  if (strlen($piece) == 0)
    continue;

  if ($piece[0] == "x") {
      $size = strlen($piece); 
      $value = (isset($values[$counter-1])) ? $values[$counter-1] : "";
      $value = htmlspecialchars($value);

      echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"{$name}_$counter\" value=\"$value\"
        size=\"$size\" maxlength=\"$size\" class=\"VOLGENDE\"/>";

      $counter++;
   } else {
      echo $piece;
   }
}

{/php}
{if $comments}
  <div class="cf_field_comments">{$comments}</div>
{/if}
```

I need to add some javascript to this, but I cannot manage to get it working. This is the javascript that needs to be added:

```
$(".VOLGENDE").keyup(function () {
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
  $(this).next('.VOLGENDE').focus();
}
});
```

With this script, I am trying to make sure that the focus will be put on the next field once the maximum amount of characters in a given field is reached.

I am looking for a way to include this javascript into the MySQL database field where the PHP code mentioned above is found. If there is anybody who could help me out with this, then that would be great :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing in this code relating to MySQL in any fashion. Is this *code* in the database? If so, that's not really relevant, though it is kind of scary.

Comment: Yes, the code is in the database.